# What is a possible future weapon of mass destruction?

Tags: post-apocalypse, weapon-mass-destruction

Instead of using nuclear weapons as a cause of an early civilization collapse (I feel like that's too generic), what are some alternative weapons that could trigger the start of a new era?

Comment: Hi you may wish to visit [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to get accustom to the rules and guidelines ;D

Comment: [The Nude Bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nude_Bomb)

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is an interesting question, but can you edit it to be more specific? What is the state of the world pre-disaster, what technology is available, what specific effects are desired? Right now the question is in the closing queue but imo it's still workable with some edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is potentially something that could be resolved with a quick [internet search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_of_mass_destruction#Definitions_of_the_term), but the easy answers:

- Chemical weapons.  Some weapons, like [VX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VX_(nerve_agent)), have extraordinary environmental persistence.  If it were a desired property, a chemical agent could doubtless be developed that could render an area unsafe for human habitation for decades.  Dispersing such an agent widely in a war would almost certainly have negative effects on civilization.  A non-persistent but extremely lethal agent would also be effective, particularly if it was easily synthesized.  If a recipe for a "kill everything in a 10-block radius" nerve agent could be made in any high school science lab and were published on the Internet, Bad Things would doubtless happen very quickly.
- Biological weapons.  Here there's a wide variety of options.  In warfare, a virus that destroys crops that haven't been specifically engineered to resist it might starve all opponents to the state releasing the virus.  Terrorist cells using increasingly-available [editing technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRISPR) could make a virus or bacterium and release it in a city, only to see it spread worldwide.  A lab trying to develop a viral treatment for a disease might inadvertently create a [zombie apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feed_(Grant_novel)).
- Space terrorism.  Some advance in technology makes space travel really easy.  A religious terrorist group, seeking to bring about the Rapture, coats a big asteroid in black paint and lobs it at Earth.

If all you want is a high body count, you don't need nukes, they're just visually impressive.

Comment: Don't forget good old nano-machines!

Comment: Weber's Fourth Imperium ([note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Armageddon_Inheritance)) wiped itself out, apparently by accident, with a bio-weapon... that's certainly workable! They also had the ability to trigger supernovas or destroy planets with what you might think of as a "black hole bomb", but the tone of the question makes it sound like those might be a little extreme...

Comment: @ArkensteinXII - I don't really buy nanomachines as an Apocalypse How except in _very_ squishy sci-fi.  The problem of powering and coordinating them means that rather than grey goo, you're going to get something more like a green goo, and then you're back to bioweapons

Comment: @jdunlop You make a fair point! Green goo does sound rather cool though!

Answer (score 0):

## Automation

Once nobody has a job anymore, what do you think the poor and dispriveledged will do? War will ensue.

Comment: Forget war. Once nobody has a job, they start forgetting how to maintain their technology. Then something happens to it... A few might survive, but they may well be thrown back into the stone age, and that assumes they're still physically capable of surviving without technology.